# HTTPS download file error android 4.4

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

I have just such a problem, the following small code image downloader where params[0]- url and params[2] - file name, this design works well on Android 5.0+, but on older versions, I get an error:

> -javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        is = new URL(params[0]).openStream();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Exception there
    }
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    OutputStream outStream = null;
   File file = new File(Constans.DATA_APPLICATION_PATH+"/photo/"+params[1].replace("\"","").trim());

    try {
        // make a new bitmap from file
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    file.deleteOnExit();
   return bitmap;
}
```

`

Comment: I think this is something to do with the certificate, which he can not handle, but I tried to remove the test certificate of authenticity, but it did not help

Comment: problem is closing) Just did't use a ssl, but ansewer @Samrat Das,my help any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with SSL authorization, which will come for sure if you are using self signed certificates.

So the way to make android app to connect to URL is to skip the SSL verification (Only if we are sure about the connection)

For this you can add [this class](https://newfivefour.com/android-trust-all-ssl-certificates.html) and execute it inside onCreate method

```
new NukeSSLCerts().nuke();
```

It will skip certificate verification by trusting all certificates.

Comment: does not work for me, I probyval several methods on how to disable certificate verification, neither worked, this method uses the API level 21, but Android 4.4 uses a 19 level and 17 level generally 4.2

Comment: I am using this method, and it is working even for api level 15.